# Mongodb group and project operators

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to group by "group_name" and select fields "group_name" and "group_id" with php driver using aggregation framework:

```
Array
(
    [$project] => Array
        (
            [group_name] => 1
            [group_id] => 1
        )

    [$group] => Array
        (
            [_id] => $group_name
            [total_sum] => Array
                (
                    [$sum] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I'm getting this: `[errmsg] => exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`
However, when I'm using only `$project` or `$group` operator it works just fine.

Comment: Comma separate?
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

Comment: I'm using comma in the code. This is just output of it. Is my structure correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your grouping your $project and $group together.

Your array should look more like

```
{
  $project: {
    group_name: 1,
    group_id: 1
  },
},
{   
  $group:{
    _id:{
      group_name:'$group_name',
    },
    total_sum:{$sum:1}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reformat and also use commas as separators. It's a pipeline so it takes each item in at a time.

I haven't tried this but try:

```
array
(
array(
array(
    '$project' => array(
        "group_name" => 1,
        "group_id"   => 1,
    )
),

array(
    '$group' => array(
        "_id" => array("group_name" => '$group_name'),
        "total_sum" => array('$sum' => 1),
    ),
)
)
```

Comment: I'm using commas in the code. This is just output for simplicity. Why did you put one extra array over another one? And no, didn't work